# I want to change to float to double in cuda source code

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to change floats to doubles. I tried to change the data type of float to double, but that was not what I expected and caused an error.

My source code is HERE

```
main
int *imgData_0;
int *imgData_1;
int *imgData_2;

dim3 dimGrid(6500);
dim3 dimBlock(256);

kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock,0,stream>>>(imgData_0,imgData_1,imgData_2);

kernel
__global__ void kernel(int *imgData_0,int *imgData_1, int *img_Data_2)
int n = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*256

double *imgData_f_0;  //original Data type is float
double *imgData_f_1;
double *imgData_f_2;
double *before_conv_x,*before_conv_y,*before_conv_z;

before_conv_x=(double*)imgData_0;
before_conv_y=(double*)imgData_1;
before_conv_z=(double*)imgData_2;

before_conv_x[n]=imgData_0[n]/4095.0;
before_conv_y[n]=imgData_1[n]/4095.0;
before_conv_z[n]=imgData_2[n]/4095.0;
```

If it is printed, some values are good but the others are strange.

```
[506] : 0.862027
before_conv_x[507] : 0.862027
before_conv_x[508] : 0.862027
before_conv_x[509] : 0.861050
before_conv_x[510] : 0.857143
before_conv_x[511] : 0.857631
before_conv_x[43296] : -403653.072283
before_conv_x[43297] : 261911.558242
before_conv_x[43298] : 513530.716728
before_conv_x[43299] : 261909.432234
before_conv_x[43300] : 120122.646398
before_conv_x[43301] : 261909.057143
```

If I try it with float, I get the correct values.
Why does the value of double come up like that?

Is the problem regarding the memory? or thread?

I don't know why.

---

EDIT

I try this

```
range = IMAGE_SIZE_X * IMAGE_SIZE_Y;
double *before_conv_x = new double[range];
double *before_conv_y = new double[range];
double *before_conv_z = new double[range];

before_conv_x[n] = ((double)imgData_0[n]) / 4095.0;
before_conv_y[n] = ((double)imgData_1[n]) / 4095.0;
before_conv_z[n] = ((double)imgData_2[n]) / 4095.0;
```

but that is not worked

The operation is copied after copying the data of imgData to before_conv_x

so I think

```
before_conv_x=(double*)imgData_0
```

that is correct code.. but why return not value?

Is it different from reading memory because of data type?

---

EDIT :

I found the error

I try this code

```
printf("imgData_0[%d] : %f \n", n, (double)(imgData_0[n]));
```

Error when converting data type.

The value seems to be good, but it seems to be an error in the value due to memory violation.

SO Change the INT to DOUBLE 4 bytes remain.

How can I initialize the value by putting 0 in these 4 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this code is probably in:

```
before_conv_x=(double*)imgData_0;
before_conv_y=(double*)imgData_1;
before_conv_z=(double*)imgData_2;
```

`before_conv_` and `imgData_` are pointing to the same memory and in the next step you assigning the `double` value to this memory `before_conv_[n]=imgData_[n]/4095.0;`.
The previous code works good because the size of `int` and `float` was the same. 
Now to fix it you shouldn't use `before_conv_=(double*)imgData_;` but you should create new `double* before_conv_x= new double[n];`

Edit:

```
double *before_conv_x = new double[`size`];
double *before_conv_y = new double[`size`];
double *before_conv_z = new double[`size`];

before_conv_x[n] = ((double)imgData_0[n])/4095.0;
before_conv_y[n] = ((double)imgData_1[n])/4095.0;
before_conv_z[n] = ((double)imgData_2[n])/4095.0;
```

Comment: I try this but Still the same hm.... i remove ```before_conv_=(double*)imgData_;``` and create ```double* before_conv_x= new double[n];```

Comment: @NAMENAMEKANG what is it `double *imgData_f_0;`? do you use it somewhere?

Comment: that is After ervery operation , saved the value. is it problem?

Comment: @NAMENAMEKANG did you tried something like in the edited answer?

Comment: @NAMENAMEKANG qand if you want to assign the all data from `imgData_` to the `before_conv_`  like it was made in `before_conv_=(double*)imgData_;` you need to copy it manually (probably, because I don't know another way) in some kind of loop

Comment: Yeah ,,  same .... hu ... thank you .... I think I should keep trying